# Strange character inside dates in "net user" command output

Tags: windows-command-prompt

When running the `net user username /domain` command in `cmd`, all the dates (`Password last set`, `Password expires`, `Password changeable` and `Last logon`) have a strange character before the individual dates numbers, like:

```
Password last set      ⌠2019-⌠11-⌠27 09:22:20
```

When I copy and convert that character to HEX, I get `E2808E` (the *'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' U+200E* Unicode character).

**What is causing this?  I'm guessing it's a setting on the Active Directory server?**

I'm extracting the value in a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims= " %%f in ('net user %username% /domain ^| find /I "Password expires"') do set expire=%%f %%g
set "expireDate=%expire: =" & set "dummy=%"
echo %expireDate%
```

And I get:

```
?2019-?11-?27
```

Comment: I've actually been wondering about this, too. It's not Active Directory-related. It occurs with local accounts on non-Domain-joined machines, too. I've only seen this behavior on Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 computers. I don't see it with Windows Server 2012 or 2012 R2 or earlier OS's. It occurs whether I'm using the new console or legacy console on Windows 10.

Comment: `find.exe` does not understand Unicode and shows `?` (as a common string replacement character) instead. Hence, you can use `%expireDate:?=%` to get a _valid_ date…

Comment: Yeah @JosefZ, that's what I'm using to clean it, but I'm curious about the source of the 'issue'.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `net.exe`. Those _Left-To-Right Mark_ characters appear in all dates in `net.exe` output e.g. `NET STATISTICS Workstation`, `NET TIME` etc. Maybe an user with experience in _right-to-left_ writing system (ANSI 1255-Hebrew or ANSI 1256-Arabic) could know more?